# Group by a set of Values (Check-In or Check-Out)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a simple table which records people clocking-in and clocking out like so.

```
Id     | EmployeeNumber | InOutId | InOutDateTime
-----------------------------------------------------
1      | 505            | IN      | 2015-03-24 08:32:42:000
1      | 506            | IN      | 2015-03-24 08:35:47:000
1      | 507            | IN      | 2015-03-24 08:46:12:000
1      | 505            | OUT     | 2015-03-24 16:59:00:000
1      | 506            | OUT     | 2015-03-24 17:05:00:000
```

I want to show the total people currently IN and those currently OUT. In other words: 
- Total IN means those that do not have a corresponding OUT for that given day. - Total OUT means those that do have an IN and an OUT for that given day.

So, based on my table above, I want to get the following results:

```
TotalCurrentlyIn     | TotalCurrentlyOut 
-----------------------------------------
1                    | 2
```

This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @d date;
set @d = cast('2015-03-24 15:02:42.000' as date)

select EmployeeNumber, InOutId, InOutDateTime from MyAttendance
where
    InOutDateTime >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @d), 0)
    and InOutDateTime < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @d) +1, 0)
order by 
  EmployeeNumber, InOutId
```

I need to be able to sum and group by - any ideas?

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
 DECLARE @d date;
    set @d = cast('2015-03-24 15:02:42.000' as date)

    ;with cte as(
    select t.EmployeeNumber,t.InOutId as in1,
    t1.InOutId out1,t.InOutDateTime from @t t
    left join (select EmployeeNumber,InOutId,InOutDateTime from @t 
    where InOutId='OUT' and cast(InOutDateTime as date)=cast(@d as date) ) t1 
        on t.EmployeeNumber=t1.EmployeeNumber and 
        cast(t.InOutDateTime as date)=cast(t1.InOutDateTime as date)
            where t.InOutId='IN' and cast(t.InOutDateTime as date)=cast(@d as date))
    select count(in1) Totalin,count(out1) Totalout,   sum(case when out1 is null then 1 else 0 end) TotalCurrentlyIn 
    ,count(out1) TotalCurrentlyOut  from cte
```

data

```
declare @t table (Id int,EmployeeNumber int, InOutId varchar(3), InOutDateTime datetime)
insert into @t(Id, EmployeeNumber,InOutId, InOutDateTime) values
(1      , 505            , 'IN'      , '2015-03-24 08:32:42:000'),
(1      , 506            , 'IN'      , '2015-03-24 08:35:47:000'),
(1      , 507            , 'IN'      , '2015-03-24 08:46:12:000'),
(1      , 505            , 'OUT'     , '2015-03-24 16:59:00:000'),
(1      , 506            , 'OUT'     , '2015-03-24 17:05:00:000')
```

Comment: its not giving the count of employee who are either In or out on that particular date, its displaying for a particular employee

Comment: employees are coming i want the count of employees who are in or out on a particular date... like on 21 december how many emplyess are out and In

Comment: 'total in' and 'total out' has been added into the solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

CheckIn = 1 and CheckOut = 2 so you need to check last entry of all the uses.

`Select EmployeeId, ActionType, Max(ActionDateTime)
From AttendanceLog 
Where
    ActionDateTime >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @d), 0)
    and ActionDateTime < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @d) +1, 0)
Group by 
    EmployeeId, ActionType
Order by 
  EmployeeId,ActionType`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question. you need to know how much person is in the office right now:

the first query return the max date for any employee, than you join it with the actionType

```
select
EmployeeId , max(ActionDateTime) as MaxActionDateTime into #temptable
from table
group by EmployeeId 


select count (EmployeeId), ActionType
from table inner join #temptable 
on table.EmployerId == #temptable.EmployerId 
    and  table.ActionDateTime == #temptable.MaxActionDateTime
group by ActionType
```

Comment: Better to avoid the use of temp tables for performance reasons - can you provide an alternative without the use of temp tables?

Comment: you can use select in select, put the first query in ( select..)as tbl and thanjoin and  select from all tables

Comment: It worked, thanks,I wanted to filter it according to the date.

Comment: add where to the first query:
    where CONVERT(date, ActionDateTime) == CONVERT(date,@D)
    and ActionDateTime<= @D

Answer (score 0):

Using a windowing function you can get the last action for every employee and count those

```
With data As (
  Select id, EmployeeNumber, InOutId
       , lastAction = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeNumber 
                                         ORDER BY InOutDateTime DESC)
  From   table1
)
Select Count(CASE InOutId WHEN 'IN' THEN 1 END) TotalCurrentlyIn
     , Count(CASE InOutId WHEN 'OUT' THEN 1 END) TotalCurrentlyOut
From   data
Where  lastAction = 1
```